# Asp.Net MVC JavaScript doesn't work after loading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing Asp.Net MVC application.
I'm using partial view for menu in Layout form for some views. I need use JavaScript on this view, but its work only on first time - after view loaded. Later - doesn't. Partial View is like this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Html.CheckBox("IsChoosed", true, new { onclick = "FormReload();" })

<script>
    $(".IsChoosed").on("onchange", function () {
        FormReload();
    });

    var FormReload = new function ()
    {
        alert("FormReload");
    };

</script>
```

LayoutForm:

```
@Html.Partial("_ViewPartial")

@RenderBody()
```

Alert message is displayed after loading of page, when checkbox value set. But after while i'm changing value - doesn't.
I tried to move JavaScritp methods to ***.js file and hook up it in view, but its worked the same way.
Where can be an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `change` event is not firing because you are trying to attach to the class `.IsChoosed`.

try changing your `change` handler to:-

```
$("#IsChoosed").on("onchange", function () {
     FormReload();
});
```

so `#IsChoosed` instead of `.IsChoosed`.

**EDIT**

Also, change:-

```
var FormReload = new function ()
```

to this:-

```
function FormReload()
```

Comment: ieaglle, BG101, thank you very much! I changed code like you told, but its still don't work. Also it strenge that alert message is displayed after pade loading and later not.

Comment: If they helped, give them an upvote and mark the relevant answer as correct  :^)

Comment: BG101, i'm sorry, it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.CheckBox("IsChoosed",...` - first argument is **name**.

Selector `$(".IsChoosed")` looks for **class** `IsChoosed`. So `onchange` callback is not set.

To fix you can do the following:

```
@Html.CheckBox("IsChoosed", true, new { @class="IsChoosed", onclick = "FormReload();" })
```

Comment: ieaglle, thank you very much! I changed code like you told, but its still don't work. Also it strenge that alert message is displayed after pade loading and later not